# Select Input:File programmatically in Webbrowser control VB.net 2010

Tags: vb.net, browser, webbrowser-control

I have a website where I am filling form data through VB.Net 2010 through WebBrowser control.

I am able to set value for input:text, input:password, checkbox, select and able to submit form.

But I am not able to select input:file programmatically. I am also able to open 
"Choose a File" Dialog.

How can I send file name to select and press OK button from VB.Net Code?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure this is a browser security feature to prevent malicious web-sites from auto-uploading random files from the user's website to themselves. Consider how dangerous it would be if any website could pull arbitrary files off the user's computer without any explicit action from the user.

Your best bet is probably going to be dumping the Web Browser control since it will limit you to its security model. Instead consider directly getting the web page and posting a response within your application.

The following .NET namespaces should come in handy for that:
[System.Net.HTTPWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
[System.Net.TTPWebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.aspx)

Comment: Hi John, I agree with you. But its not about JS. This is VB.net where we can handle window and can automate whatever we can. Only workaround which I am looking for is, 
1. how to locate opened file dialog window
2. Select file by sending message to window
3. Close the dialog
But I don't know how to achieve this through code.

Comment: I think the browser control is what is going to kill you here. By using it you are limiting yourself to its security model. Have you considered directly reading the web page and posting the response from your application? I updated my answer to include this approach.

Comment: but I dont have a single form. I have sequence of pages which are opened one by one after logging into the system. So its not possible to post data without following the sequence.

Comment: I'm suggesting you use the HTTPWebResponse class to read the contents of the page, then use the HTTPWebRequest to post back the data circumventing the need for the browser control which is blocking your requests in the interest of security.

Comment: but some pages are having javascript only to post the data as they are using token while opening a page.
Do you have a example where I can look into and try if I can have sequence of request-response interactions.

Comment: Try googling those two namespaces and you should find plenty of examples. I don't have any on standby. I'm just telling you that the browser control is likely a dead end and trying to point you to alternatives. You are going to have to do the legwork on your own.